# Unsigned / Signed Arithmetic Problems from A Programmer's Perspective Textbook

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, unsigned, twos-complement

```
int x = random();
int y = random();

unsigned ux = (unsigned) x;
unsigned uy = (unsigned) y;
```

For each of the following C expressions, you are to indicate whether or
not the expression always yields 1. If it always yields 1, describe the underlying mathematical principles. Otherwise, give an example of arguments that make it yield 0.

```
A. (x<y) == (-x>-y) 
B. ((x+y)<<4) + y-x == 17*y+15*x
C. ~x+~y+1 == ~(x+y)
D. (ux-uy) == -(unsigned)(y-x)
E. ((x >> 2) << 2) <= x
```

---

For these questions, I got that only A could yield 0 while the rest always yielded 1.

I know this is probably wrong and I'm not looking for direct answers but I was hoping to get some general knowledge / advice on how to approach these problems.

I have a really bad professor and I've been trying to find resources online but I don't really know where to start or what to look for. I know the basics of unsigned / two's complement arithmetic and bit-shifting but I don't know how to apply it to find counter cases for these problems.

Comment: A should always be 1 ...

Comment: If `x == INT_MIN` (for example) it might not be because `-INT_MIN` is not representable as `int` on machines that use two's complement representation (as virtually all modern computers do). The expression would cause undefined behavior (not just have an unspecified value) in that case.

Comment: In fact, for all expressions except D there exist values for `x` and `y` that make them cause undefined behavior or have unspecified value, making the question unanswerable as it is stated -- they may or may not yield `0` for those values or do something else entirely. I suspect that the book doesn't know the rules for signed integer overflow (nor signed bitshift) and just assumes that compilers won't optimize based on them. FreeBSD was [recently bitten](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2015-February/054320.html) by such an assumption.

Comment: Oh, for D as well, e.g. `y = INT_MIN`, `x = 1` (causing integer underflow on the right-hand side of the expression, and thus undefined behavior). When I wrote the last comment, I read that as though `ux` and `uy` were used on the right-hand side as well as on the left-hand side.

Comment: @Wintermute I just ran a test with those values for D and it still works for me. I think we're to assume that the value would wrap / be truncated? Not sure if that's the reason why it works though.

Comment: Well, that's the thing about undefined behavior: What you get this time may not be what you get next time. If you're supposed to assume that signed overflow just wraps and that signed bitshift sign-extends, the question has an answer, but it'll not (always) correspond with real-world results.

Comment: you should add some informations about the range of the `random` function. If it is http://linux.die.net/man/3/random it will only return values from `0` to `RAND_MAX`, which is the same as `INT_MAX` on my machine. Therefore A, D and E should not invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C programming language does not specify the result of an overflow of integral signed quantities; neither it defines `x << n` if `x` is signed and negative.

However, it is not uncommon that arithmetic operations are performed regardless of the sign, considering both signed and unsigned n-bit integers to be numbers modulo 2^n represented in the two's complement system.

This must be assumed for your exercise, which is almost meaningless otherwise.

Example for 8-bit integers:

```
unsigned domain: (0..127), ( 128..255)
signed   domain: (0..127), (-128..-1)
```

in binary representation:

```
unsigned domain: 00000000..01111111 and 10000000..11111111
signed   domain: 00000000..01111111 and 10000000..11111111
```

Between signed and unsigned, only the representative system of the integers
modulo 2^n differ, which is relevant for printing, but not for internal
computations (as long as only `+`, `-`, `*` and bitwise operations are used).

For signed integers, exactly the negative integers have the first bit set to
1. Casts between signed and unsigned are irrelevant except for printing.

I insist, this is assumed for your exercises, but the C programming language
does not specifies most of my claims.

A. `(x<y) == (-x>-y)`

Is disproved by `x == INT_MIN`, `y == INT_MIN + 1`,
because `INT_MIN == -INT_MIN`.

B. `((x+y)<<4) + y-x == 17*y+15*x`

True:

```
   ((x+y) << 4     ) + y-x
== ((x+y) * 0x10000) + y-x
== ((x+y) * 16     ) + y-x
== 17 * y + 15 * x
```

C. `~x+~y+1 == ~(x+y)`

True:

```
x + ~x + 1 == 0
~x + 1 == -x
~(x+y) + 1 == -(x+y)
~(x+y) + 1 == -x + -y
~(x+y) + 1 == ~x + 1 + ~y + 1
~(x+y) == ~x + ~y + 1
```

D. `((unsigned)x-(unsigned)y) == -(unsigned)(y-x)`

True: the cast from signed to unsigned is assumed not to change the internal
representation, and operators are assumed to ignore the signedness of
integers. In other words, `x-y == -(y-x)` holds wherever casts are put.

E. `((x >> 2) << 2) <= x`

True:

```
   x 
== (x >> 2) << 2 + two_last_significant_bits_of_x
== (x >> 2) << 2 + positive
>= (x >> 2) << 2
```

Examples with signed 32-bit integers:

```
x              == 5
x              == 00000000000000000000000000000101 in base2
x >> 2         == 00000000000000000000000000000001 in base2
(x >> 2) << 2  == 00000000000000000000000000000100 in base2
(x >> 2) << 2  == 4

x              == -5
x              == 11111111111111111111111111111011 in base2
x >> 2         == 11111111111111111111111111111110 in base2
(x >> 2) << 2  == 11111111111111111111111111111000 in base2
(x >> 2) << 2  == -8
```

Comment: I do believe that your answer for C is incorrect, by taking x and y to both be 0 the left side would evaluate to 3 with the right side as 1.  Thanks for a complete and well written answer anyway!

Comment: @JeffreyCordero In C with `x == 0` and `y == 0`, both sides evaluate to `-1`, whose bits are all 1.

Comment: @Loic in C I think  "In other words, x-y == -(x-y) holds wherever casts are put." should say "In other words, x-y == -(y-x) holds wherever casts are put."